# Combobox binding empty using OnNavigatedTo method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm new to using Prism WPF and have a basic understanding of how it works and how to structure an application.

I am having trouble with binding data to controls in the view, specifically using the 'OnNavigatedTo' method.

**Approach 1**

I understand that the 'OnNavigatedTo' method is called after the constructor, however when I call the repository to fill Customers, the ComboBox in the view is empty.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public ViewAViewModel(IRepository repository, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        Customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    private string _selectedCustomer;
    public string SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCustomer, value); }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        Customers = _repository.GetCustomers();
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }
}
```

View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewA"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"             
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCustomer}"></ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>    
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If I initialise/fill 'Customers' through the constructor, the ComboBox binding works fine, however, when the module is added to the Module Catalog in the Bootstrapper the 'Customers' repository method is called unnecessarily. I assume this is not ideal.

**Approach 2**

If I use 'RaisePropertyChanged' on 'Customers', then binding data to the ComboBox works fine.

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private List<Customer> _customers;

    public List<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return _customers; }
        set
        {
            _customers = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ViewAViewModel(IRepository repository, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _customers = new List<Customer>();
    }

    private string _selectedCustomer;
    public string SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return _selectedCustomer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCustomer, value); }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        Customers = _repository.GetCustomers();
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Is Approach 2 the correct approach to take? Or am I missing something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The second approach is correct. Since the `Customers` property is a binding source, it has to raise the `PropertyChanged` event in order to inform the binding that it should update its target. This is actually a general data binding topic, it has nothing to do particularly with Prism or navigation.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the miscategorisation. Its my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach is wrong because you are not calling the RaisePropertyChanged.
On the constructor you are assigning a new empty list to the Customers property so the combobox start empty.

On a second time, on the OnNavigatedTo method you are assigning the populated list to the Customers property, but the Customers property don't call the RaisePropertyChanged so the view won't be aware of the changes.

You can fix it exactly like your 2nd approach, which is the generally right approach.

Another solution is to just populate your list on the constructor instead of populating it on the OnNavigatedTo, in this case the Customers property don't need to call RaisePropertyChanged because the view will be constructed already with the updated elements.

But this have sense only if the Customers property won't be changed anymore when you are in the View.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a third approach: instead of `List<Customer>`, an `ObservableCollection<Customer>` can be used. It can be created in the constructor and filled with data just later. The view will update since it will be listening to the `CollectionChanged` events.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. 
`Customers` in the scenario above would be a ‘one way’ binding source i.e. not changed in the view. 
From an application performance point of view, loading `Customers` data through the constructor is not ideal, correct? As I mentioned in my question above, when a module is loaded into the module catalog the constructor on the viewmodels inside that module are called (loading the data etc.) and then when navigating to that view, the constructors are called again. Maybe I have misunderstood how binding works and/or Prism.